# Activerecord: Pluck specific columns and association's association counts

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Alright, so we have `Accounts` which has many `Schedules` which has many `Impressions`.

I want to get `Accounts.name`, all of `Accounts.schedules`, but only plucking `Accounts.schedules.date`, `Accounts.schedules.summary` and also the count of `Accounts.schedules.impressions`

Here's a visualization of what I want given 1 account (I'll want all accounts)

```
Account:  
    .name
    Schedules
        .date
        .summary
        count(Schedule.impressions)
```

And here's what the code would look like with too many queries

```
Account.find_each do |account|
    puts a.name # Account.name
    a.schedules.each do |schedule|
        puts schedule.date # Account.schedule.date
        puts schedule.summary # Account.schedule.summary
        puts schedule.impressions.count # Count(Account.schedule.impressions)
```

I'd like to do this in as few queries as possible, and maybe learn something too! I love efficiency and optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a select Query

```
Account.
  joins(schedules: :impressions).
  select("accounts.name as account_name, 
          schedules.date as schedule_date, 
          schedules.summary as schedule_summary, 
          count(impressions.id) as schedule_impression_count" ).
  group("accounts.name,schedules.date,schedules.summary")
```

Should do it in a single query then the objects will respond the the column alias' like `schedule_date` and `schedule_impression_count`

If you need to use these objects for other data in the same view then `Account.eager_load(schedules: :impressions)` should also work and will also execute a single query.

Comment: Is there any way I can group by accounts.name? So when I loop through them, all of the schedules for the same name are in a single array?

Comment: @Phatso727 you could add something like `group_by(:account_name)` to the end of the method which will convert the object to a `Hash` like `{account1 => [ActiveRecord::Relation], account2 => [ActiveRecord::Relation]}` or you can use the `eager_load` method.

Comment: With this query, my goal is to load just the specific info I want to display on a view, and if life were perfect, I'd be able to execute a single query and pass the results directly to the view which will only do a simple loop over the data to display it. Would you suggest I use ruby's group_by, or the eager_load method?

Comment: @Phatso727 do you need any additional data other than the data created by the joins query? e.g. do you need account information other than the name in the view?

Comment: Nope! Just the info gathered by the query. However, it'd be nice to also have the total number of impressions for each account.