# rails pluck has_many through count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I pluck associated data using ActiveRecord?

I'd like to have two columns returned, `PatientProfile.name` and `PatientProfile.recommendations.length`

I've tried the below using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081020/activerecord-pluck-specific-columns-and-associations-association-counts)

```
class PatientProfile
  has_many :recommendations

PatientProfile.joins(:recommendations).select("patient_profiles.name as name, count(recommendation.id) as rec_count")
```

Comment: `count(recommendation.id)` should be `count(recommendations.id)` unless you overrode the database table for `Recommendation` model to `recommendation`

Comment: @MichaelGorman this isn't working for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost `.group` from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081020/activerecord-pluck-specific-columns-and-associations-association-counts).
Try this if you need `pluck`(i.e. array is expected as output):

```
PatientProfile
  .joins(:recommendations)
  .group(:id)
  .pluck(:name, 'count(recommendations.id)')
```

Grouped by `id` to avoid non-uniq `name` for different `PatientProfile`. Depending of your app logic you may change it for `.group(:name)`
Output is 2d array:

```
=> [['aa', 4],
['bb', 2],
['cc', 1]]
```

If you need relation as output, try:

```
PatientProfile
  .joins(:recommendations)
  .group(:id)
  .select(:id, :name, 'count(recommendations.id) as rec_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel this should work:

```
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  SELECT patient_profiles.name, count(patient_profile_id) AS rec_count 
  FROM patient_profiles INNER JOIN recommendations ON 
  recommendations.patient_profile_id = patient_profiles.id GROUP BY 
  patient_profile_id
")

res.to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a model Tags that had `has_many: company_tags` in the model definition, but those company_tags were stored in a table named `yeet_companies_tags`. To get the count of the companies using each tag I had to use:

```
Tag
  .joins(:company_tags)
  .group(:id)
  .pluck(:id, :name, 'count(yeet_companies_tags.id) as usage_count')
```

That returns the tag id, tag name, and count of the companies using the tag.